# Karate - How to send request with client certificate

Tags: karate

I test a Rest API with KarateDSL, which goes very well. But currently I'm trying to send request with authentication via client TLS certificates.

Curl looks like this:

`curl -X POST https://<urlOfEndPoint> -d '{ "id":"First","status":"Active" }' --cert cert.crt:password --key cert.key --insecure`

Is it some way, how to send this request from Karate? Or some workaround?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just searched and saw this question since I ran into the same issue too.

Comment: My solution is to convert my key/cert file by using openssl using "openssl pkcs12 -export -in /path/to/your/cert.pem -inkey /path/to/your/key.pem -out /path/to/output/cert.p12 -password pass:${pwd}"
and then feed your cert.p12 to the Karate config like Peter mentioned below.
* configure ssl = { keyStore: 'file:/path/to/output/cert.p12', keyStorePassword: 'yourPwd', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' };
Then it should be setup correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the doc and examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate#x509-certificate-authentication

```
# enable X509 certificate authentication with PKCS12 file 'certstore.pfx' and password 'certpassword'
* configure ssl = { keyStore: 'classpath:certstore.pfx', keyStorePassword: 'certpassword', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' };
```